# PHP - Can't seem to redirect my php files to link to another file that is in another folder

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

i am a beginner in PHP and I am trying to learn how to make a simple registration form with mysql and php.

The problem is I cannot link to another file that is in another folder. Here are some pictures:

1. [image: localhost redirectory error]

Even though i have placed this in my index.php codes and for other files.

```
<?php 
        session_start(); 

        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
            header('location: pages/login.php');
            exit();
        }

        if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
            session_destroy();
            unset($_SESSION['username']);

        }

    ?>
```

I have huge problems trying to understand how to identify the error when I include this line for a server connection in my register.php

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>
```

However it will only work if I place all the files outside of their own respective sub folders, even though I had placed the directory address. I don't understand, please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: server.php in which folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include `server.php` in your register page you need to use `require('../server.php')`. The two dots is a shortcut/alias for the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

if your index.php and server.php in inside same folder 
then you should use 
`include 'server.php'` 
else first specify the directory for example if **server.php is inside /home/homeFirst/server.php** 
then do this 

`include '/home/homeFirst/server.php';`